# CardView takes space of elevation after elevation removed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview

When i decrease elevation of CardView it takes the space of elevation
This is normal pic:-
[image]

This is when clicked:- 
[image]

This is when clicked again where i try to set it elevation back to normal:- 
[image]

Item clicked is (1,2)

Here is my cardView code :-

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view_categories"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#fffff7"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
```

OnClick on Card View:-

```
@Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    if (i % 2 == 1) {
                        mAddIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,
                                R.drawable.settrans);
                        mAddIcon.startAnimation(anim);
                        mAddIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_done_black_24dp);
                        i++;
                        Categories cat = new Categories();
                        cat.mCategory = mCategory.getText().toString();
                        mSelectedList.add(cat);
                        Random rnd = new Random(); 
                        String[] color= {"#F44336","#FF4081","#9C27B0","#7C4DFF","#009688","#00BCD4","#8BC34A","#CDDC39","#FF5722","#607D8B"};
                        int index = rnd.nextInt(color.length-1);
                        String item = color[index];
                        //int color = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));   
                    //  card.setBackgroundColor(color);
                    //  card.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(item));
                    //  mCategory.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
                        card.setElevation(50);
                    } else {
                        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,
                                R.drawable.settrans);
                        mAddIcon.startAnimation(anim);
                        mAddIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_add_black_24dp);
                        i++;
                        Categories cat = new Categories();
                        cat.mCategory = mCategory.getText().toString();
                        mSelectedList.remove(cat);
                        mCategory.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                    card.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#fffff7"));
                        card.setElevation(10);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Can you post your `CardView` xml code.

Comment: actually i have `CardView` and i am able to set elevation programmatically and size is same only elevation changing. Post your `onClick` code and i'll look at it.

Comment: i have two solution. Actually my onclick method is same with you but i am using `view.setElevation` instead of `card.setElevation` , first of all can you try this .

Comment: @YasinKaçmaz working fine

Comment: glad to fix your problem , now i will post an answer for future visitors including both ways. I am using `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` and both ways working perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting elevation or translationZ of `View` instead of `CardView` will help you.

```
public boolean press=false;
cardviewrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          if(!press){
              v.setTranslationZ(50); 
              //or you can use 
              v.setElevation(50); 
              press=false;
          }else{
              v.setTranslationZ(0);
              //or you can use 
              v.setElevation(0);
              press=true;
          }
        }
});
```

If you dont want to get warnings about minimum Api level use this :

```
if(isLolipop()) v.setTranslationZ(50); 

public static boolean isLolipop(){
  return  Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP;
}
```